# LAContext change UIAlertController button title

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, touch-id

I've incorporated TouchID into my app with `LAContext`, like so:

[image]

However, I'm wanting to change the name of the button title from "Enter Password" to enter "Enter Security Code" (or something like that), like this:

[image]

How would I go about changing that button title?

Here's the `LAContext` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/index.html) and here's my code:

```
var touchIDContext = LAContext()

if touchIDContext.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &msgError) {
   touchIDContext.evaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: touchIDMessage) {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if success {
            println("Success")
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Yup, it did. I set your answer as correct.

Comment: @Cody hi can u please share how you change the alert title "Touch ID" to "Touch ID for "XXXX" "

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the localizedFallbackTitle property:

Objective-C:

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
context.localizedFallbackTitle = @"YOUR TEXT HERE";
```

Swift:

```
var touchIDContext = LAContext()
context.localizedFallbackTitle = "YOUR TEXT HERE"
```

Comment: nice answer...i was wondering how to change Title for touch id alert. e.g 
"Touch ID for *********  ".   my text goes at *******.

Comment: anyway.. I got the answer. Thanks anyway

Comment: @iAnurag : what is the answer of your question ?

Comment: @ hi can u please share how you change the alert title "Touch ID" to "Touch ID for "XXXX" "

Comment: @Balu - The "XXXX" is automatically filled from the App name within your info.plist

Answer (score 2):

From Apple Documentation, `localizedCancelTitle` is available for iOS 10

```
// Fallback button title.
// @discussion Allows fallback button title customization. A default title "Enter Password" is used when
//             this property is left nil. If set to empty string, the button will be hidden.
@property (nonatomic, nullable, copy) NSString *localizedFallbackTitle;

// Cancel button title.
// @discussion Allows cancel button title customization. A default title "Cancel" is used when
//             this property is left nil or is set to empty string.
@property (nonatomic, nullable, copy) NSString *localizedCancelTitle NS_AVAILABLE(10_12, 10_0);
```